# Probability problem with multiple percentages

Tags: probability

> At a university, 28% of the students major in zoology.  Of all the students majoring in zoology, 68% are males.  It is also known that 56% of all students at the university are male.
>
> Let Z represent the event that a randomly chosen student is majoring in zoology.  Let M represent the event that a randomly chosen student is male.
>
> (a)  What is the probability a randomly chosen student is male and majoring in zoology?
>
> (b)  What is the probability that one randomly selected student is a male or is majoring in zoology, or both?
>
> (c)  What proportion of males at the university are majoring in zoology?
>
> (d)  What proportion of students are male and are not majoring in zoology?

I'm not sure how to answer these questions so I would be grateful for some help!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At a university, 28% of the students major in zoology.  Of all the students majoring in zoology, 68% are males.  It is also known that 56% of all students at the university are male.
>
> Let Z represent the event that a randomly chosen student is majoring in zoology.  Let M represent the event that a randomly chosen student is male.

Write down what you do know.   $\mathsf P(Z)=0.28, $ and so on.

> (a)  What is the probability a randomly chosen student is male and majoring in zoology?

You seek $\mathsf P(M\cap Z)$.   Express that in terms of what you do know and evaluate.

$$\mathsf P(M\cap Z) = \mathsf P(M\mid Z)\;\mathsf P(Z)$$

And so forth.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot! I'm still unclear about part d, when Z complement gets thrown into the mix, would you know how to do that? I know that were trying to solve for P(Zc ∩ M) but I'm not sure how to do it